# For a GitHub commit I am showing up as both coauthors

Tags: git, github

I am able to commit an push from my terminal but I am showing up as both coauthors of the commit. I am not sure why. I've tried many things online but none of the solutions solve mine.

I've tried `git config --global user.email "my email"` but I get `"error: could not lock config file /.gitconfig: Permission denied".`
My user.name and user.email are both correct when I type `git config -l`. 
For some reason when a command has the`--global` flag it won't let me change. Cause I don't have permissions.
I am still able to commit it just shows us as "John Doe authored and John Doe committed 1 hour ago" instead of the desired "JohnDoeUser committed 1 hour ago."
My commits were showing up as the desired way a few days ago, but suddenly they show up as coauthors now.

The desired way
[image]

What I've been getting
[image]

Comment: What does running `echo "$HOME"` produce?

Answer (score 1):

You have two separate but related problems here.

First, GitHub shows your commits with your full name instead of your handle when you use an email address that is not registered with your GitHub account to commit (usually via `user.email`).  If you want to see both the author and the committer information on your local machine so you can troubleshoot, you can use `git log --format=fuller`.  If you want your commits to be associated with your GitHub account, either use an email address already registered with GitHub or add the one you're using to GitHub.

The other issue you're seeing, which is the failure to set values with `git config --global`, is likely due to you lacking a value for or having the wrong value for your `HOME` environment variable.  Git uses this environment variable to find your home directory, which is where your global `.gitconfig` file is stored.

You haven't told us what platform you're running on, but for Unix systems such as macOS and Linux, `HOME` should be set automatically when you log in or create a terminal session, and you can see what it's currently set to by running `echo "$HOME"`.  On Windows, you may need to set the value yourself.

If the value of `HOME` is empty or is `/` (or on some systems, you're running as `root`), that may result in the message you're seeing, and you'd need to either not run as root or figure out why `HOME` is not set automatically (perhaps by looking at your shell configuration) and fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a commit with one or more co-author is [described here](https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-commit-with-multiple-authors)

It always involve the string "Co-authored-by:" in the commit message.

Try a new commit in a shell session, with your account, and push it from there: check if the issue persists.